How to use a specific version of methylprep in Jupyter notebook
I am trying to use a package named Methylprep. It is using "append" function for dataframe, which has been removed since pandas 2.0.
Now the version of pandas installed in my pc is 2.2.2.   And I am using jupyter notebook to process my scripts. Is there a way to allow me use specific version of pandas (maybe 1.8) in the script I am currently testing in jupyter notebook ?
Thank you very much !!
import methylprep
from pathlib import Path
filepath = Path('test/')

data_containers = methylprep.run_pipeline(filepath, array_type=None, export=True, manifest_filepath=None, sample_sheet_filepath='test/MethylationEPIC_Sample_Sheet_B.csv')

INFO:methylprep.processing.pipeline:Running pipeline in: test
Reading IDATs: 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:41<00:00, 41.74s/it]
INFO:methylprep.files.manifests:Reading manifest file: HumanMethylationEPIC_manifest_v2.csv
Processing samples:   0%|                                                                        | 0/1 [00:01<?, ?it/s]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_9268\2686656903.py in ?()
----> 1 data_containers = methylprep.run_pipeline(filepath, array_type=None, export=True, manifest_filepath=None, sample_sheet_filepath='test/MethylationEPIC_Sample_Sheet_B.csv')

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\methylprep\processing\pipeline.py in ?(data_dir, array_type, export, manifest_filepath, sample_sheet_filepath, sample_name, betas, m_value, make_sample_sheet, batch_size, save_uncorrected, save_control, meta_data_frame, bit, poobah, export_poobah, poobah_decimals, poobah_sig, low_memory, sesame, quality_mask, pneg_ecdf, file_format, **kwargs)
    327 
    328         batch_data_containers = []
    329         export_paths = set() # inform CLI user where to look
    330         for idat_dataset_pair in tqdm(idat_datasets, total=len(idat_datasets), desc="Processing samples"):
--> 331             data_container = SampleDataContainer(
    332                 idat_dataset_pair=idat_dataset_pair,
    333                 manifest=manifest,
    334                 retain_uncorrected_probe_intensities=save_uncorrected,

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\methylprep\processing\pipeline.py in ?(self, idat_dataset_pair, manifest, retain_uncorrected_probe_intensities, bit, pval, poobah_decimals, poobah_sig, do_noob, quality_mask, switch_probes, do_nonlinear_dye_bias, debug, sesame, pneg_ecdf, file_format)
    586         self.manifest = manifest # used by inter_channel_switch only.
    587         if self.switch_probes:
    588             # apply inter_channel_switch here; uses raw_dataset and manifest only; then updates self.raw_dataset
    589             # these are read from idats directly, not SigSet, so need to be modified at source.
--> 590             infer_type_I_probes(self, debug=self.debug)
    591 
    592         super().__init__(self.sample, self.green_idat, self.red_idat, self.manifest, self.debug)
    593         # SigSet defines all probe-subsets, then SampleDataContainer adds them with super(); no need to re-define below.

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\methylprep\processing\infer_channel_switch.py in ?(container, debug)
     15     -- runs in SampleDataContainer.__init__ this BEFORE qualityMask step, so NaNs are not present
     16     -- changes raw_data idat probe_means
     17     -- runs on raw_dataset, before meth-dataset is created, so @IR property doesn't exist yet; but get_infer has this"""
     18     # this first step combines all I-red and I-green channel intensities, so IG+oobG and IR+oobR.
---> 19     channels = get_infer_channel_probes(container.manifest, container.green_idat, container.red_idat, debug=debug)
     20     green_I_channel = channels['green']
     21     red_I_channel = channels['red']
     22     ## NAN probes occurs when manifest is not complete

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\methylprep\processing\infer_channel_switch.py in ?(manifest, green_idat, red_idat, debug)
    167     red_in_band['meth'] = oobG_unmeth
    168     green_in_band['unmeth'] = oobR_meth
    169 
    170     # next, add the green-in-band to oobG and red-in-band to oobR
--> 171     oobG_IG = oobG.append(green_in_band).sort_index()
    172     oobR_IR = oobR.append(red_in_band).sort_index()
    173 
    174     # channel swap requires a way to update idats with illumina_ids

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in ?(self, name)
   6295             and name not in self._accessors
   6296             and self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name)
   6297         ):
   6298             return self[name]
-> 6299         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'


Yes, you can use environments to isolate your versions related to an environment. See about that here. That may be best though to try first without Jupyter as connecting Jupyter is harder because of the way the kernel is in relation to the kernel environment. It can be done though. The Anaconda Distribution takes this idea further to be more powerful by managing your environments and packages. You can set up and activate an environment where you run the version of Pandas you need. See ...

 here and the answer above it about nb_conda_kernels for options to connecting Jupyter if you need to go to that. Those would allow you to do this locally. You may though not want to mess with your system though if other stuff is good in general. So for this you may prefer to deal with AWS or Google and pay for a remote machine you can put on whatever you want. Or if the computational demands are modest, you can use MyBinder.org to get a free temporary session that you can configure to have the version of Pandas you need. ...

 I'm not seeing that I have a version with Pandas 1.8 (are you sure that is the correct version? I just tried installing that one and it wasn't a choice that worked.) that I can point you at right now, but here is running with an earlier version right now. Go to that link and press 'launch binder' badge there. That one will have Pandas version 1.5.1 upon start of the session. You can upgrade that to 1.5.3 by opening a new notebook there in the Jupyter session and in a new cell running %pip install pandas==1.5.3. ...

 I am assuming you are trying to avoid versions 2 and above since that has some significant differences. (Usually you can adjust the code modestly and get things working in Pandas 2, but if you aren't ready to do that this can help.) You can also drag-and-drop things like input files from your local computer into the file navigation pane on the left to get them into the temporary MyBinder-served Jupyter session. As it is temporary session on a remote machine, you'll wand to immediately download anything useful you make right back to your local system.

HuggingFace.co offers 'Spaces' where you can run JupyterLab. See here to get started. The default JupyterLab one they have presently comes with Pandas 2.2.2; however, you can run in the  notebook %pip install pandas==1.5.3 and it will uninstall that and install the version 1.5.3 so that you can try and use that. It offers more computing power than MyBinder-served Jupyter sessions, but you have to register for an account. The free tier gives you more power than MyBinder offers, too.

@Wayne Thank you for the suggestions. How to modestly modify the code to fit pandas 2 ? Will be interesting to try that . Thank you very much !

For the 'append()' step, you probably want to try concat(), see here. And actually someone already made the changes here. You can do what it says at the bottom to implement it. Fork the repo and pull in the change. Oh wait, it already is here, so I think you can just clone and use?

@Wayne I was trying to install this fork via "pip install -e git+git://github.com/gilgameshjw/methylprep/tree/pandas2.0#egg=methylprep"  But it tells me this link cannot be found. But when try the link of its master it was installed successfully. Does it mean this link is not active anymore ?

I'd have to look later at pip install from a repo. I don't recall egg being in there, but I'd really have to look. I had just been thinking you could clone it and swap in the files that were changed. Or use that to edit the code in the places that are changed where you have the methylprep package. on your system.

Based on my knowledge of pip install with repos and branches on GitHub, I put this command together: pip install git+https://github.com/gilgameshjw/methylprep/@pandas2.0_0. It seems to run a successful install. And then I even tested it since I realized the repo has example data, see test tun of methylprep working with Pandas 2 here.

It would also be better if you updated the title of your original post to be specific, please, see the section 'Write a title that summarizes the specific problem' in How do I ask a good question?. You weren't looking for how to do this for a specific package and that should be in the title. Imagine if you were looking for the pertinent post to your issue in a list of post titles. Consider this one would probably be less striking to you than 'How to use a specific version of methylprep in Jupyter notebook'?

"Now the version of pandas installed in my pc is 2.2.2."
Running Methylprep in conjunction with that version of Pandas would be the more productive way forward. You'll otherwise be fighting against the current of development.
Luckily, someone already did the conversion here, and filed this related pull request at the original Foxotech 'methylprep' source repo. You can go ahead and use that for now, until it is integrated in the source software.
The command to pip install that particular version of Methylprep would be the following in a terminal where you are sure you are in the environment Jupyter will be using:
pip install git+https://github.com/gilgameshjw/methylprep/@pandas2.0_0

Or more conveniently, run the in the notebook to use the magic install command that insures the installation from inside a running notebook occurs in the environment the kernel is actually using. (
See more about the modern, magic %pip install command here.)
%pip install git+https://github.com/gilgameshjw/methylprep/@pandas2.0_0

It seems to run a successful install. And then I even tested it in conjunction with Pandas 2.2.2 since I realized the repo has example data, see test run of methylprep working with Pandas 2 here.
(In the test notebook, I link to above, I didn't run that install command in the notebook because I wasn't actually planning to test the running until I saw there was example data and thought I'd try. But I put the command in a code cell in the notebook as a magic install command so that anyone curious can step through running the notebook itself or the commands I show right inside a test notebook in fresh session launched from where I indicate at the top of here, all without touching or installing anything on your local system. This enables testing it works first before you mess with your local machine.)

Thank you Wayne, perfectly resolved. I tried with conda to configure the environment, it works, but slightly more work to find out the right versions of some other packages, scipy, statsmodels.....      One more question is what is the "@" before the "panda2.0" representing ? In another word, how do your formulate that url to enable the correct downloading ?

The @ prefaces the branch tag. Since where I referenced works you can use %pip list result from there (viewable [here]) to check versions that worked in the test I ran. Then use conda to install those specific versions in your environment. Try to use Anaconda/conda as much as you can. In this case you'll need to use pip for the special version of methylprep since it won't have a conda recipe.

To install a specific version of the pandas library, you have two options:

Using the shell: Open your terminal or command prompt and run the following command:

pip install pandas==1.8


Using Jupyter Notebook: you can add a new cell and use the %pip magic command to install pandas. Add the following code in a new cell:

%pip install pandas==1.8

Run the cell, and it will install pandas version 1.8 within your Jupyter Notebook environment.

Did you try the commands you suggest to verify they work?
